# How to run a c++ build file inside a python script?

Tags: python, c++, subprocess

Basically, I am trying to make some mesh models watertight using an algorithm. The algorithm is already built in C++ and can be run using the following command:

```
./manifold ../examples/input.obj ../examples/manifold.obj
```

Here I have to pass an input object, and the algorithm will output an object named manifold. I have thousands of input objects in different directories. And I am using a Python script to extract those input objects. The code is provided below.

```
def input_object(folder):
    for sub_folders in os.listdir(folder):
        for x in os.listdir(folder+sub_folders):
            if x == 'models':
                for y in os.listdir(folder+sub_folders+'/'+x):
                    if y == 'model_normalized.obj':
                        print(y)

                        #I want to execute the build file here


root = './02880940/'
input_object(root)
```

**I want to execute the build file inside this commented area of the script.** How can I do that? I am not well-versed in C++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you had in mind?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command

Comment: There's probably some confusion here due to a very unfortunate choice of words. "Building" and "object files" have a common meaning in C++ that's utterly unrelated to this question. C++ converts source code into executables in two steps. This process is commonly called "building" and the intermediary files after the first step are called object files. But *this* question is not about C++ at all. There's some executable called `manifold`, and for all we care it could be written in FORTRAN.

Comment: @MSalters thanks for clearing up the confusion. apologies for the wrong choice of words.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes. I have solved the problem using the subprocess module. Thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever heard of subprocess? if your C++ code is already built, simply import subprocess and call the run function.
something like this:

```
import subprocess
def input_object(folder):
    for sub_folders in os.listdir(folder):
        for x in os.listdir(folder+sub_folders):
            if x == 'models':
                for y in os.listdir(folder+sub_folders+'/'+x):
                    if y == 'model_normalized.obj':
                        print(y)

                        #I want to execute the build file here

                        subprocess.run("manifold.obj")

root = './02880940/'
count_messages(root)
```

something like this